# Connecting to remote HBase with Java

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hbase

I'm trying to establish a connection to a remote HBase on a cluster provided by my school, but it fails.
I execute the code as below on my own machine without HBase:

```
public class HBaseApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ServiceException {

        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        HBaseAdmin admin = null;

        String ip = "149.202.86.142";
        String port = "2181";

        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", ip);
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", port);

        try {
            admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
            boolean bool = admin.tableExists("myTable");
            System.out.println("Table exists? " + bool);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my "error":

```
16/11/01 21:50:11 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Reading reply sessionid:0x1579b929b8e0d06, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 65,4  replyHeader:: 65,4297753995,-101  request:: '/hbase/meta-region-server,F  response::  
16/11/01 21:50:11 DEBUG zookeeper.ZKUtil: hconnection-0x42591130-0x1579b929b8e0d06, quorum=149.202.86.142:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Unable to get data of znode /hbase/meta-region-server because node does not exist (not an error)
16/11/01 21:50:12 DEBUG zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Reading reply sessionid:0x1579b929b8e0d06, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 66,4  replyHeader:: 66,4297753995,-101  request:: '/hbase/meta-region-server,F  response::  
16/11/01 21:50:12 DEBUG zookeeper.ZKUtil: hconnection-0x42591130-0x1579b929b8e0d06, quorum=149.202.86.142:2181, baseZNode=/hbase Unable to get data of znode /hbase/meta-region-server because node does not exist (not an error)
```

And so on.

I used Maven to link the dependencies.

I have to precise that I have no control on the server's configuration.
Does anyone know what did I miss?

Regards